# How to create file 11.txt 22.txt ... 99.txt with regEx?

Tags: regex, shell, command-line

I try used regular expressions about generate file.

Example

> 11.txt 22.txt ... 99.txt

I used regEx with pattern `touch {1..9}{1..9}.txt` 

Results is

> 11.txt 21.txt 31.txt .... 99.txt

it not worked for me.
I do not want to regEx like `{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99}.txt`

Please recommend technical me.

Comment: I sorry for my knowledge. I'm learning it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is useful for you:

```
$ seq -f'touch %g.txt' 11 11 99
touch 11.txt
touch 22.txt
touch 33.txt
touch 44.txt
touch 55.txt
touch 66.txt
touch 77.txt
touch 88.txt
touch 99.txt
```

to create files on disk:

```
 $ seq -f'touch %g.txt' 11 11 99|sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\d)\1` use this construction in your regex `\1` is mean double prev expression